# Vim Comments Format Options Repeat Not Working

Tags: vim, comments

I set the `comments` option for a filetype to `b:*`. If I open such file I can verify this with `set comments?`. Now further I explicit set the `formatoptions` to use `r` for repeating the comment on a new line. After all calling `set formatoptions?` return in sum `j1tcqln`.
If open a new line `o` and write something like `* This is a comment` hit `<CR` I expect to get a `*` on the new line es well, cause the `r` option, but is doesn't.
The check if the `+comments` feature is available with `:echo has('comments')` is positive and returns `1`.
Whats the problem here?

**Edit:**
This is my `ftplugin/markdown.vim`:

```
setlocal comments=b:*,b:-,b:+,b:>
setlocal formatoptions+=r
setlocal formatoptions-=c
echom 'Format: ' . &formatoptions
```

The last line leave a correct message when open a file with this type. But calling `:echo &formatoptions` manually afterwards, its again the false output.

It seems like no matter what I do in this `ftplugin` afterwards its not there anymore, even though it has been executed.

**Edit:**
It looks like my `ftplugin` gets overwritten by the default one in `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplguin/`. Does this make sense and how can I mix them up?

Comment: I dont see `r` in `j1tcqln`.

Comment: @phd that's correct. I'm confused. If I insert an `echom &formatoptions` into the `ftplugin` I get `tqj1r`. But if I call `:set formatoptions?` afterwards manually I get `j1tcqln`. Can I find out where this is reset?

Comment: But if I now add `r` manually again, it doesn't seems to work either.

Comment: Extended question...

Comment: `:verbose set formatoptions?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filetype plugins are sourced in this order, each potentially overriding the preceding one:

```
$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim
$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim
$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim
```

--- edit ---

The first location is suitable for two scenarii:

- you are creating support scripts for a language not natively supported by Vim,
- you want to prevent Vim from sourcing the default support script for a specific filetype (the solution in your answer).

The second location is off-limits. Four main reasons for this:

- your changes can and will be overridden during future updates,
- your changes may make Vim unstable,
- having to sudo your way to your config will get annoying pretty quickly,
- put *your* stuff in *your* `$HOME`.

The third location is sourced last so it allows you to selectively override default settings and add your own. This is the safest place for your own filetype-specific settings.

Comment: I guess that's true for all other files like <filetype>_somethin.vim as well? When should I use the first folder?

Comment: Yes, this applies to all support files. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add this at the header of the `ftplugin` file:

```
if exists('b:did_ftplugin') | finish | endif
let b:did_ftplugin = 1
```

Then is necessary cause the `ftplugin` in `/usr/share/nvim` gets loaded after and does not been executed if this variable is set.